# double free or corruption (fasttop) in my encoder

Tags: c, tree, free, encoder

My program involves combining tree lists in a queue, my program compiles perfectly and works for about half of the code then throws this error at me. I have narrowed it down to involving my freeTree and how i call it in encodefile,  for some back story this is for an encoder that is based off of character frequencies in a textfile, so if there is a textfile with 5 different chars in it, then this code will start with 5 different nodes in the queue. Each initial node in the queue holds the char and the frequency, the priority queue is based off of frequencies, with a tiebreaker as the numeric value of the char.

```
malloc_printerr (action=3, str=0x7ffff7b98938 "double free or corruption (fasttop)", ptr=0x6034b0) at malloc.c:5027
```

This is what the structs look like, symbol stands for the char, and the weight is the frequency

```
struct treeNode
{
  unsigned char symbol;
  unsigned long weight;
  struct treeNode* left;
  struct treeNode* right;
  struct treeNode* next;
};

struct queue
{
  struct treeNode* first;
  struct treeNode* last;
};
```

This is my freeTree method

```
void freeTree( struct treeNode* root )
{
  if( root != NULL )
  {
    freeTree( root->left );
    freeTree( root->right );
    free( root );
  }
}
```

These are the variables or treeNodes i use in the main part of my code

```
  struct treeNode* newNode;
  struct treeNode* holder;
```

And this is where it is all being called that should be going through my queue combining two nodes into one tree with a node on top equal to the weight of both of the input nodes, and this should go on until the queue only contains one big tree

```
while( treeCount > 1 )
  {
    newNode = combineTwo( q->first, q->first->next );
    if( charCount == 2 )
    {
      holder = q->first;
      q->first = q->first->next;
      freeTree( holder );
      holder = q->first;
      q->first = newNode;
      freeTree( holder );
    }
    else
    {
      holder = q->first;
      q->first = q->first->next;
      freeTree( holder );
      holder = q->first;
      q->first = q->first->next;
      freeTree( holder );
      insertSortedNode( q, newNode );
    }
    charCount--;
    holder = NULL;
  }
```

And this is my combineTwo method, that will make the two input nodes into leaves on one node

```
struct treeNode* combineTwo( struct treeNode* first, struct treeNode* second )
{
  struct treeNode* newNode = createNode( '\0', (first -> weight) + (second -> weight));
  if( first -> weight > second -> weight )
  {
    newNode -> right = first;
    newNode -> left = second;
  }
  if( first -> weight < second -> weight )
  {
    newNode -> left = first;
    newNode -> right = second;
  }
  if( first -> weight == second -> weight )
  {
    if( first -> symbol > second -> symbol )
    {
      newNode -> right = first;
      newNode -> left = second;
    }
    if( first -> symbol < second -> symbol )
    {
      newNode -> left = first;
      newNode -> right = second;
    }
  }
  return newNode;
}
```

I will be here all day to answer any questions needed, if more info is needed

Comment: What is `treeNode.next` a pointer to? Is it one of the child nodes?

Comment: `while( treeCount > 1 )` What is treecount ? http://stackoverflow.com/q/23529555/905902

Comment: treeNode* -> next works with the queue, when next is called it will go into the next node in the queue and that page you linked for me does not exist

Comment: treeCount is the number of elements or trees in the queue, so like the example i gave if the input file has 5 different characters then my code will make a queue with 5 different treeNodes

Comment: @Happilystoned: yes, it still exists. (for some people)

Comment: whatup with that downvote, let me know what the problem is don't just downvote me, i am present and will be all day, oh, well then crap, why can't i look at it?

Comment: Is it possible for a treeNode's `next` pointer to point to its own offspring?

Comment: that is possible, it has been working for the rest of my code but i can start testing different cases to see if that happens

Comment: ya the q->first->next seems to stay different from q->first, the error appears when calling free after it hits its first actual tree with more than 1 node

Comment: Hmm i might have to look more into how it is looking through the trees, that seems to be some of the problem, i think it's going through them way wrong, ill get back to you guys soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`combineTwo` makes a new node which (potentially) points `newnode`'s `left` and `right` to the `first` and `second` parameter values. The code in your while loop then frees those pointers using `freeTree`.

For example:

```
newNode = combineTwo( q->first, q->first->next ); // newNode->left = q->first (possibly)
if( charCount == 2 )
{
  holder = q->first;
  q->first = q->first->next;
  freeTree( holder );      // freeing the original q->first here. newNode still points to it.
```

You need to work out whether the new node's left and right should point to the original tree nodes, or whether they (the original nodes) should be deleted. You can't do both without having invalid pointers.

Comment: Ohhhhh, that makes a lot of sense, i'm still a little iffy though about then how i would decrease the size of the queue, could i just assign two new nodes first = q->first and second = q->first->next and then call combineTwo( first, second ) and would that get rid of the error or would they be pointing to q->first potentially still giving the same error? NM that, ya didn't work

Comment: Well now i understand that but like stated above now my problem is how would i be able to combineTwo and still shrink the queue without receiving the error, i would upvote you but i don't have 15 rep

Comment: You can just remove the items from the queue without freeing them as you have moved the pointer into the tree. `q->first = q->first->next;` will do that. You end up with a big tree and an empty queue. I am not sure how your code is supposed to work though, as you never set `newNode->next` when you put it back in the queue.

Comment: I'd suggest working it out on paper first to see how the nodes are supposed to combine and where they end up.

Comment: okay ill try implementing that, and what puts the newNode back into the code is the insertSortedNode, it will do everything it need to be place back in the queue in the right spot, and will do on that second comment